# How do I call a JavaScript function from an html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I call a JavaScript function from html.erb

in **application.js**

```
function displayClock() {
  var digital = new Date();
  var hours = digital.getHours();
  var minutes = digital.getMinutes();
  var seconds = digital.getSeconds();
  var amOrPm = 'AM';
  if (hours > 11) amOrPm = 'PM';
  if (hours > 12) hours = hours - 12;
  if (hours == 0) hours = 12;
  if (minutes <= 9) minutes = '0' + minutes;
  if (seconds <= 9) seconds = '0' + seconds;
  dispTime = '<b>'+hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds + ' ' + amOrPm+'</b>';
  document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = dispTime;
  setTimeout('displayClock()', 1000);
}
```

and in **home.html.erb**

```
displayClock();
```

but it's not calling function!

Comment: On which event you want to call it? And use <script/> tag to enclose your function.

Answer (score 26):

You probably need to use proper tag to indicate that you're writing JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  displayClock();
</script>
```

Plus, since you probably use jQuery (it's default in Rails), you may want to make sure the function is called after whole document is loaded:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).load(function(){
    displayClock();
  });
</script>
```

I'd also advice you not to write your JS in `application.js` and use this file only as a manifest file, which includes your other scripts through Rails [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).

Also you can take advantage of the javascript helper [javascript_tag](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-javascript_tag) in your `html.erb` file

```
<%= javascript_tag "displayClock()" %>
```

Comment: @user3459701 did you try my answer? Did it help?